# Одинаковая замена данных в большом количестве файлов

Tags: excel, vba

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеем: большое количество таблиц в формате *Excel*

Что требуется: автоматически работать со значениями в таблице.

Пример:
А1[image: пример]

1)Количество строк неизвестно, т.е конец диапазона работы - конец таблицы.
Нужно, по примеру, от *B2* до *B(последняя_строка)* поставить значение 0,3 (0,3 = const, не меняется). Можно ориентироваться по А, т.е. смотрим координаты последней записи *А*, и столько же строк будет иметь столбец *B*.

2) *C2:D(последняя_строка)* удаляем значения, оставляем пустым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге должно получится так:

(x x x x - конец файла, т.е на деле этой строки нет, я просто обозначил так конец файла. )

Скрин 3: Отсутствие значений  - конец файла. Т.е на практике А/B/C/D:11 - нет, остается пустым и никак не затрагивается.

Как это должно выглядеть правильно?

Comment: друга - vba обрабатывает 20 000 файлов со строками и их заменой или просмотром за 5 мин... 
Поставь грамотно задачу -  и тебе помогут...
В твоём вопросе - полнейшая белиберда ...Ногу заменить на ручку в строке N и перенести вёдра в пункт A 

ПОМОГИТЕ !!!!
сам то понял что написал ???

Comment: Как ее поставить грамотно? 
1) Начало T2 и до Tx, x - последняя строка документа. Всему этому ставим значение 0,3. 
2) Начало - U2 и конец ARx, т.е получается выделяется x строк, и 24 столбца. Все имеющиеся значения удаляем, оставляем пустым.

Comment: решай тогда если тебе все понятно !!! в чем проблема  ???

Comment: так лучше? Добавил пример

Comment: nRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'в первом столбце последняя не пустая строка

далее что ?

Comment: со строки 2 и до последнеи не пустой -
ячеику(2) строки заполняем значением 0.3

Comment: Извини. Ничего не понял. Это VBA ? Ранее опыта не имел с этим. Что конкретно писать ? Как в итоге должен выглядеть код?

Comment: for 2 to nRow
sh.cells(i,2).formulaR1C1 = "0,3"
next

Comment: Я еще добавил 1 пример. Глянь. Надеюсь тебе станет понятнее. И очень надеюсь на твою помощь.

Comment: найти последнюю строку в столбце 
поставить значение от 2 до последнеи строки в столбце 2 = 0,3 
очистить значения в строках от 2 до последнеи в стоблбцах с 3 по 24

Comment: Можешь готовый код скинуть в ответ, а не в комментарий ? Заранее - огромное спасибо. Еще раз обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пакетная обработка файлов. Макрос разместить в общем модуле любой книги.

Рядом с этой книгой расположить папку *files2000*, в которой разместить все файлы, предназначенные для обработки. Путь к папке и ее имя можно выбрать другие, изменив при этом строку кода

```
sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\files2000\"
```

Диапазоны задаются в строках

```
.Range("B2:B" & lRw).Value = dValue
.Range("C2:D" & lRw).ClearContents
```

Значение для внесения в диапазон столбца *В* задано константой. Можно без нее - прописать значением в строке

```
.Range("B2:B" & lRw).Value = 0.3
```

**Макрос**

```
Sub DataChange()
Dim wBook As Workbook
Dim sPath As String
Dim sFName As String
Dim lRw As Long
Const dValue As Double = 0.3
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\files2000\"

    sFName = Dir(sPath & "*.xls*", vbDirectory)

    Do While sFName <> ""
        Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath & sFName)

        With wBook
            With .Worksheets(1)
                lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

                If lRw > 1 Then
                    .Range("B2:B" & lRw).Value = dValue
                    .Range("C2:D" & lRw).ClearContents
                    wBook.Save
                End If
            End With

            .Close
        End With

        sFName = Dir 
    Loop

    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
    MsgBox "OK", 64, ""
End Sub
```

**Определение последней строки**

```
.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - последняя видимая заполненная ячейка столбца А
```

В обрабатываемых файлах должны быть раскрыты все строки (сняты фильтры, если есть), иначе диапазон строк может определиться неверно.

Найти нижнюю границу по размеру пользовательского диапазона (принимаем, что в строке 1 находится "шапка" таблицы):

```
lRw = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Недостаток этого варианта - в диапазон попадут все форматированные строки, в том числе и без данных (такое часто встречается при неумелом копировании: заполнено 10 строк, а диапазон - на миллион).

Диапазон заполненных строк относительно ячейки:

```
lRw = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
```

При этом должна быть уверенность, что диапазон данных неразрывен (данные не разделены пустыми строками и стобцами)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Очистить_лист()
nRow = Лист1.Cells(Лист1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'в первом столбце последняя не пустая строка
nCol = Лист1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column ' определили номер  последнеи колонки с хоть одной заполненнои ячеикои
For i = 2 To nRow
    Лист1.Cells(i, 20).FormulaR1C1 = "0,3"
    Лист1.Range(Cells(i, 21), Cells(i, nCol)).ClearContents
Next  
End Sub
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лист1.Range("A3:A5").ClearContents

сделаи запись макроса  - выполни очистку диапазона и прочитаи макрос

Comment: я вообще ничего не понял. Проблема не решена. Но спасибо за твои старания. 

(nRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To nRow
 sh.Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "0,3"


    Application.Goto Reference:="Òåñò1"
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    Application.Goto Reference:="Òåñò1"
End Sub
)

Comment: Друга  - находишь последнюю строку в столбце и от 2 строки и до последнеи для столбца 3 ставишь значения , и со столбца 4 по столбец 24 очищаешь значения .

Условия задачи кинь в тему  - получишь ответ

Comment: Может я скину 2 реальных файла, т.е с которыми реальная работа происходит. Один - до ручной замены, второй с ручной заменой. Может так понятнее будет? Могу даже 4, чтобы было понятно, что каждый раз количество строк разное. Но, во всех столбцах количество строк одинаковое.

Comment: кидаи нет проблем

"что каждый раз количество строк разное. Но, во всех столбцах количество строк одинаковое"

Comment: Пока загружаю - глянь.
Готовый, почти, код.
Sub Макрос5()
'
' Макрос5 Макрос
'

'
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0.3"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B10"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B1:B10").Select
    Range("C1:D10").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
Единственное вместо B10 и D10 - нужно вставить переменную, которая будет принимать значение последней строки. Чтоб сразу весь файл автоматически обрабатывало.

Comment: Вот ссылка на яндекс диск: https://yadi.sk/d/GOZUx19G3WYN7Z
До - в T было пусто, стало 0,3. 
C U по AR - была всякая ерунда, которую нужно было удалить. В этом вся суть.

Comment: изменил ответ .
сохраните документ как книгу с макросами. 
откроите вкладку разработчик.
добавьте в книгу модуль.
в модуль добавьте код ответа .
выполните макрос и посмотрите на листе 1 изменения.

Comment: Спасибо большое ))

Comment: не за что   
в результате задача  
определить последнюю не пустую строку и колонку на листе   
в колонку 20 поставить значение для всех непустых строк  = 0.3  
все остальные колонки ,начиная с 21 очистить до последнеи не пустои строки

Comment: Единственное - туплю на базовом еще. Открыл окно разработка. Как добавить модуль, и куда добавлять код ответа? Остальное вроде все норм.

Comment: правой кнопкой на книге  - инсерт модуль  .
в модуль скопировать код  . 
поставить курсор перед Sub надписью .  
нажать энтер или выполнить макрос ...  
можно добавить код прямо на лист .  

тогда вместо Лист1 - Me

Comment: на вкладке разработчик добавьте кнопку на лист  и кнопке назначьте макрос ...отличный сайт для vba  - http://www.programmersforum.ru/

Comment: @Eikhner, обработка в цикле лишняя, можно одним диапазоном. Не забывайте декларировать переменные

Comment: друга можно привести ещё несколько вариантов решения данного вопроса , vba безграничен ... с диапазонами , словарями , регионами и прочим прочим , не возражаю , все что здесь пишут  - все правильно почти всегда ...

Comment: @Eikhner, нет, для данной задачи цикл - это неоправдано лишние вычисления. Так же здесь не имеет смысла применение массивов, словарей. Зачем в булочную ехать дорогами пол-часа, если можно тропинкой дойти за 5 минут? Я пишу не о том, что код плохой, только лишь замечание о неоптимальности